# how would i render a normal map of a model?

Tags: modeling, normal-map, height-map

let's say I have a bunch of rope models (all the deep crevices and spirals. multiple ropes together). I want to take that rope bundle and get the height data from that scene as a normal map.

Comment: Hi :). Sounds like a simple normal map baking. There are many tutorials on that topic, it's not complicated :))

Comment: time to do some baking